# Route for XMLRPC Service breaks default route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, xml-rpc

I'm trying to get an XML RPC service going as illustrated in the following article:
http://www.cookcomputing.com/blog/archives/Implementing%20an%20xml-rpc-service-with-asp-net-mvc

Everything works great, except the routing. It is a similar problem to what has been discussed in this SO question [MVC route conflicts with service route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036768/mvc-route-conflicts-with-service-route)

My code for RegisterRoutes look like this:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.Add(new Route("wlw/publish", new WLWRouteHandler()));

    }
```

When I put this line

```
routes.Add(new Route("wlw/publish", new WLWRouteHandler()));
```

before MapRoutes I can access the service but my normal routes does not work. I tried adding a fourth parameter:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { controller = "regex-for-!=-wlw" }

        );
```

but then I get a 403 The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good solution for this can be found here : http://weblogs.asp.net/jasonconway/archive/2009/10/23/include-and-exclude-constraints-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

I changed MapRoute to the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "home", action = "index", id = "" },
            new { controller = new ListConstraint(ListConstraintType.Exclude, "wlw") }
        );
```